# Error with check boxes in php

Tags: php, html

This is my PHP & HTML code, it all works fine, except it gives me some error as "Notice: Undefined index: attend in C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\postattentry.php on line 43"

```
<?php
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
    exit;
}
include('header.php');
?>




<div class="row-fluid sortable">
<div class="box span8">
    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
        <h2><i class="icon-edit"></i> Attendance Entry</h2>
    </div>
<div class="box-content">
    <?php
        $hour=$_GET["hour"];
        $date=$_GET["date"];
        $year=$_GET["year"];
        $sem=$_GET["sem"];
        $sec=$_GET["sec"];
        $dept=$_GET["dept"];
        $bat=$_GET["bat"];

        if((strpos($fgmembersite->UserAttrib(),"i")>0) and $fgmembersite->attentrycheck($hour,$date,$year,$sem,$sec,$dept,$bat,$fgmembersite->Userempid()))
            {
                $error = $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage();
                if(!empty($error))
                    {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';
                            echo $error;
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                if(!$fgmembersite->DBLogin())
                    {
                        die("Error Locating the Students Database.");
                    }
                if($bat=="ALL")
                    {
                        $qryae = "Select * from $fgmembersite->studtblname where dept='$dept' and year='$year' and sem='$sem' and sec='$sec'";
                    }
                else 
                    {
                        $qryae = "Select * from $fgmembersite->studtblname where dept='$dept' and year='$year' and sem='$sem' and sec='$sec' and bat='$bat'";
                    }
                if(!($uapae=mysql_query( $qryae ,$fgmembersite->connection)))
                    {
                        die("Error Locating the Students Database.");
                    }

                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
                    echo '<thead>';
                        echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td align="center">S.No.</td>';
                            echo '<td align="center">Roll No.</td>';
                            echo '<td>Student Name</td>';
                            echo '<td align="center">Attendance</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</thead>';
                    echo '<form id="attentry" class="form-horizontal" action="postattentry.php" method="post">';
                    echo '<tbody>';
                            $i=0;
                            $j=1;
                            while ($uapres = mysql_fetch_array($uapae)) {   
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo "<td>{$j}</td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$uapres['rollno']}<input type='hidden' name='rollno[$i]' value='{$uapres['rollno']}' /></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$uapres['sname']}</td>";
                                    echo "<td><div class='control-group'>
                                                <div class='controls'>
                                                    <label class='checkbox'>
                                                        <input type='checkbox' name='attend[$i]' id='attend[$i]' value='1' checked=''/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                              </div></td>";
                                echo '</tr>';
                                ++$i;
                                ++$j;
                                }
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Total</td>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Hour</td>';
                                    echo '<td>Date</td>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Year</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo "<td>{$i}<input type='hidden' name='fcount' id='fcount' value='{$i}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$hour}<input type='hidden' name='fhour' id='fhour' value='{$hour}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$date}<input type='hidden' name='fdate' id='fdate' value='{$date}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$year}<input type='hidden' name='fyear' id='fyear' value='{$year}'/></td>";
                                echo '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Dept.</td>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Sem</td>';
                                    echo '<td>Section</td>';
                                    echo '<td align="center">Batch</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo "<td>{$dept}<input type='hidden' name='fdept' id='fdept' value='{$dept}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$sem}<input type='hidden' name='fsem' id='fsem' value='{$sem}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$sec}<input type='hidden' name='fsec' id='fsec' value='{$sec}'/></td>";
                                    echo "<td>{$bat}<input type='hidden' name='fbat' id='fbat' value='{$bat}'/></td>";
                                echo '</tr>';
                                echo '<tr>';
                                    echo "<td></td>";
                                    echo "<td><button type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Register</button></td>";
                                    echo "<td><button type='reset' class='btn'>Reset</button></td>";
                                    echo "<td></td>";
                                echo '</tr>';
                    echo '</tbody>';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</table>';

            }?>

</div>
</div><!--/span-->

</div><!--/row-->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

The processing form code is...

```
<?php
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
    exit;
}
include('header.php');
?>




<div class="row-fluid sortable">
<div class="box span8">
    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
        <h2><i class="icon-edit"></i> Post Attendance Entry</h2>
    </div>
<div class="box-content">
    <?php
        echo $hour=$_POST['fhour'];
        echo $date=$_POST['fdate'];
        echo $year=$_POST['fyear'];
        echo $sem=$_POST['fsem'];
        echo $sec=$_POST['fsec'];
        echo $dept=$_POST['fdept'];
        echo $bat=$_POST['fbat'];
        echo $count=$_POST['fcount'];

        if(!$fgmembersite->DBLogin())
            {
                die("Error Locating the Students Database.");
            }

        if(!$fgmembersite->EnsureAttTable())
            {
                die("Unable to Create Attendance Table.");
            }
        $attvars = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $count) {
                echo $rollno= $_POST['rollno'][$i];
                echo $attend= $_POST['attend'][$i];
                ++$i;           }

    ?>

</div>
</div><!--/span-->

</div><!--/row-->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

I tried the same code by changing input type from the checkbox to text, it worked fine. I was unable to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Why are you not using `$i++`?

Answer (score 3):

In a form, if a checkbox is not checked, it doesn't get posted.

change:

```
echo $attend= $_POST['attend'][$i];
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['attend']) && isset($_POST['attend'][$i]){
    echo $attend =$_POST['attend'][$i]
} else {
    echo $attend =0; //or whatever value you wish
}
```

Comment: This checks if the specific box is checked aswell, the error you're getting means that a specific checkbox was not posted (because it wasn't checked), so checking if $_POST['attend'][$i] is set should prevent the error.

Comment: Itried this in all possible ways as you said and i checked all  check boxes , the error is same for entire loop... :(

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: attend in C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\postattentry.php on line 43` -
This means that the error is here: `echo $attend= $_POST['attend'][$i];` where you're trying to access the attend array. if you check if the key `isset` before accessing it, it will work. Replace this line with what i wrote, if nothing else, the error should change, if it does, paste the new error here.

Answer (score 0):

If a checkbox is not checked, it is not sent at all as a POST variable.

In order to identidity if a checkbox is not checked, you must do a logic step.

```
if (isset($_POST[attend[$i]])){
    {
        $attended=1;
    }else{
        $attended=0;   
    }
```

I am officially too slow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i did that too... Still same problem, i did made the check boxes are checked in default a.d submitted the form. Still the problem perrsists....

Comment: @user2947783 have you considered naming the checkbox fields $_POST["attend" . $i] ?

I believe the problem is with trying to make the check-box results a multidimensional array.

Comment: Yes,  i did considered $_POST["attend" . $i] , still the problem is same... If the checkboxes should not be a multi dimensional array, is there any other possible way?